# Keyframe animation :hover doesn't obey the "ease-out" part of the animation on mouse-out

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a 3 chevron animation sequence set up for a back button I designed. The animation triggers on hover exactly the way I want it to but it doesn't respect the `ease-out` part of the animation property when I hover off of the button. I know that typically with CSS animations you fix this by putting the animation on the actual element and not the `:hover` state but the problem with that is that the keyframe animation triggers on page load and gets a little wonky on `:hover`. Is there a mouse-out or hover-out-like state that I could use so that when the user moves away from the button the animation eases out or even reverses? I tried adding `animation-direction: reverse;` property to the base elements but that doesn't do anything, probably because it doesn't know what animation I'm referring to because it's not present in the base elements for the reasons above. Do I possibly need some CSS or javascript to prevent the animation from triggering until the `:hover` state actually occurs and then I could place the animation in the base elements instead of the `:hover` state?

https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/L7k1r63f/54/

```
<body style="background-color: #214365">
  <div class="backBtn">
    <div class="chevronContainer">
      <div class="backBtnChevronTop"></div>
      <div class="backBtnChevronMid"></div>
      <div class="backBtnChevronFar"></div>
    </div>
    Back
  </div>
</body>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@700&display=swap');

.backBtn {
  font-family: Oswald, Univers, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0.2rem 0em 0.1rem 0em;
  margin: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  word-spacing: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chevronContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-1.3rem) translateX(-1rem);
}

.backBtnChevronTop {
  content: url(https://i.imgur.com/YHZi17i.png);
  filter: invert(1);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 1.33rem;
  width: 1.33rem;
}

.backBtnChevronMid {
  content: url(https://i.imgur.com/YHZi17i.png);
  filter: invert(1);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 1.33rem;
  width: 1.33rem;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.backBtnChevronFar {
  content: url(https://i.imgur.com/YHZi17i.png);
  filter: invert(1);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 1.33rem;
  width: 1.33rem;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.backBtn:hover .backBtnChevronMid {
  animation: animateChevronMid 0.6s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.backBtn:hover .backBtnChevronFar {
  animation: animateChevronFar 0.6s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animateChevronTop {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  70%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


@keyframes animateChevronMid {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  70%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-0.7rem);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animateChevronFar {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  70%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-1.4rem);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: `ease-out` is not working like you think. This is the transition-timing-function and this works on the end of animation, so your animation will proceed as usuall and on the end it will be slower https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function. So this does not apply to when you move your mouse from hovered element

Comment: You can probably resolve this by adding the transition on element when there is no hover but I didn't tested this. Solution found as always on csstricks :) https://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably resolve this by adding the transition on element when there is no hover at the moment and tweak a little the keyframes. Like this:

```css
.backBtn .backBtnChevronMid {
  animation: animateChevronMid2 0.6s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.backBtn .backBtnChevronFar {
  animation: animateChevronFar2 0.6s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animateChevronMid2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-0.7rem);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  70%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateChevronFar2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-1.4rem);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  70%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

this additional keyframes are exact opposite of the keyframes that you have done. And they do apply when you move your cursor from the element (so on hover off so to speak).

Comment: So that ALMOST gets me there with the exception of the animation playing on page load. I found an article on the site you linked that has a preload element with some javascript but it's for CSS transitions and not animations. Is there a way to tailor it to animations instead?

https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/

https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/L7k1r63f/78/

Comment: you could add the animation with `animation-play-state: paused` but to be completely honest I didn't use once this. But according to docs this should stop your animation on element then you could use `load` from csstricks article to toggle it back to start. Here is the docs for animationplaystate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Comment: Okay, so through what you suggested plus a lot of javascript, I managed to get it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/L7k1r63f/985/ 

...except it doesn't work when I try to use it in my actual Visual Studio file and live site.  I immediately start getting errors in the `backBtnChevronMid.style.animation = "animateChevronMid 0.6s ease-in-out";`, the error Chrome gives me is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`. I'm not sure why the fiddle works but it doesn't work inside of the browser for the actual site.

Comment: I managed to figure out what was causing this and was also able to find a way to hide the animation within `<div>`s because I have multiple `<div>`s that this button will be used to switch between. 

https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/L7k1r63f/1097/

The last thing I cant quite get is why the `onload` with the `pauseAnimation` function only works the first time I load a `<div>`. If I back out of the child `div` to the parent `div` and go back to the child it plays the reversed animation when I load the page. Not a big deal but it's just really odd behavior that I can't seem to track.

Comment: By saying "If I back out of the child div to the parent div and go back to the child" do you mean that you are moving to another page? Because onload will work but only when your page is loaded (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event). So if you are using some type of SPA framework or something, there might not be load triggered (reactjs for example will replace content and not reload to make your site faster etc.). Using regular JS solutions is not always the best solution in for example react (there if you want this to do something on load you add it to useefect).

Comment: I actually mean another `<div>` on the same page. So the page has 4 buttons, you click a button and it runs a script to swap the parent `div` to one of the 4 child `div`s depending on which button you click. The back button is to take you back to the parent `div`. I think what's happening is that the last animation on the button is running either on div load or just running continuously until the user comes back. If `onload` only works on page load then I guess it's not going to fix that. Maybe I should look into some react tutorials and see if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Jacck is right and beat me to it.

You can use that, and add a fadeIn transition to the back button itself. It's hacky but put this on the back button:

```
  animation: fadeIn 0.6s ease-in-out;
```

And tweak the animation accordingly. It'll run once. If you don't want a fade just move the "stop" close to the end and this controls the container that holds the other animations so your whole effect won't show until it has loaded:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  95% {opacity: 0}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
```